# How many groups are there of order $11^2\times 13^2$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

How many groups are there of order $11^2\times 13^2$ up to isomorphism?

**My solution:**

There are $11$-sylow subgroups of order $11^2$ and $13$-sylow subgroups of order $13^2$.

$n_{11} \equiv 1 (\bmod11) \implies n_{11}=1,12.$

$n_{11}\mid 13^2 \implies  n_{11} \neq 12 \implies n_{11}=1.$

So $11$-sylow subgroup is normal subgroup.

$n_{13} \equiv 1 (\bmod13) \implies n_{13}=1,14.$

$n_{13}\mid 11^2 \implies  n_{13} \neq 14 \implies n_{13}=1.$

So $13$-sylow subgroup is normal subgroup.

Define$ A:=$ $11$ -sylow group normal subgroup , $B:=$ $13$ -sylow group normal subgroup.

$A,B$ are both normal subgroups so $AB$ is a subgroup.

$\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$ so $|A \cap B|=1$ (Lagrange theory) $\implies 
A \cap B={1}$.

$|AB|=\frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|} \implies \frac{11^2\times 13^2}{1} \implies G=AB.$

So $G \cong A \times B.$

We know both $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups (both order of $p^2$ when $p$ is a prime number).

$G \cong A \times B , \mathbb {Z_{11}} \times \mathbb Z_{11} \times B , \mathbb Z_{13} \times \mathbb Z_{13} \times A , \mathbb {Z_{11}} \times \mathbb {Z_{11}} \times \mathbb{Z_{13}} \times \mathbb{Z_{13}}$

So there are $4$ different groups up to isomorphism.

I'd be grateful for some feedback.

Comment: Your concluding remarks are a little unclear, for a start. How do the three equalities give four *different* groups up to isomorphism?

Comment: You've shown that $G$ is abelian correctly. I think the last line is also correct because you described the four groups correctly, but the usage of the $=$ is confusing. Actually, $G$ can be isomorphic to exactly one of the four groups that you have written on that line, and they are all not isomorphic to each other, so that completes the answer, which is correct.

Comment: Avoid the use of `*` to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming languages, not in Mathematics

Comment: @Shaun Fixed it , thank you. By the way thwn i read it again , why its right that $A \cap B={1}$ and there is no $C<G$ that |C|=143 ?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon when i read it again , why its right that A∩B=1 and there is no C<G that |C|=143 ? Thank you !

Comment: @erez $A \cap B$ is a subgroup of $A$ and a subgroup of $B$, so by Lagrange's theorem, it's order must divide the order of $A$ and the order of $B$, which are coprime numbers. This only leaves the option $|A \cap B| = 1$. It's not true that there won't be a $C < G$ with $|C| = 143$ : you could just take the group $\mathbb Z_{11^2\times 13^2}$ (which is isomorphic to $A \times B$) and take the equivalence class of $143$ in this group. But once you proved that $G$ is abelian, then the fundamental theorem of abelian groups gives you the last line.